# FROM keyword not found where expected (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently working on some select queries and am getting the error `FROM keyword not found where expected` in my last two queries, and I can;t for the life of me figure out what the problem is...

**Here are my queries**

```
SELECT Title, PubID AS 'Publisher ID', PubDate AS 'Publish Date' 
FROM Books WHERE PubID = 4 OR PubDate > '01-Jan-01' 
ORDER BY PubID ASC;

SELECT Title, (((Retail-Cost)/Cost) * 100) AS 'Markup %' 
FROM Books;
```

I am not sure if my math is correct in this one `(retail - cost / cost * 100 is the goal)`.

I have been trying for probably 45 minutes on the first query before giving up and doing the last one, to only get the same error on that one.

Comment: You need to use double quote (`"`) instead of single quotes in your column aliases. Use aliases as `PubID AS "Publisher ID"` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Which database are you actually using?  You've tagged this for both Oracle and MySQL.

Comment: @Rachcha that did the trick, idk how I didnt notice that or find anything anywhere else I was looking and pickup on the fact that it was double quotes... Been a long weekend for me I guess!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Single quotes are used to surround string literals.  Double quotes are used to surround identifiers.  Column aliases are identifiers so you'd want to use double quotes

```
SELECT Title, 
       PubID AS "Publisher ID", 
       PubDate AS "Publish Date" 
  FROM Books 
 WHERE PubID = 4 
    OR PubDate > '01-Jan-01' 
 ORDER BY PubID ASC;
```